# Xsl stylesheet embedded in View page is lost when moving External List between site collections

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I've the External List "ExtList1" with following content:

- Read List.aspx
- DispForm.aspx

"Read List.aspx" have embedded Xsl stylesheet (tag "Xsl", parent tag "WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart"

I've moved ExtList1 between site collections from CollectionA to CollectionB with using Export-SpWeb/Import-SpWeb. Related External Content Type exist in both site collections.

After that "Read List.aspx" in CollectionB does not contain Xsl stylesheet.
I also didn't find anything related to Xsl stylesheet in export.cmp archive.

Please provide a method that will prevent loss of embedded Xsl stylesheet when moving ExtList1 from CollectionA to Collection B.

Export command:

```
Export-SPWeb -force -identity $SourceSiteUrl -path $ListFilePath -itemurl ("Lists/{0}" -f $ListName)
```

Import command:

```
Import-SPWeb -force -identity $DestSiteUrl -path $ListFilePath
```

SP Version: SharePoint Server 2010 Enterprise 14.0.7113.5000